# How to calculate ambient and diffuse lightning?

Tags: 3d

I am working on my 3D software rendering application and completely stuck on lightning. I am trying to do the flat shading. I know that:

```
a = polygonAmbient * lightSourceAmbient; //a=color of ambient
d = polygonDiffuse * lightSourceDiffuse * dot (polygonNormal , lightPosition ) ;
//d color of diffuse
    polygon->color= a+d;
```

What `polygonAmbient` and `polygondiffuse` do I need to use ? Is it the same RGB value for both ?
And what about `lightSourceAmbient` and `lightSourceDiffuse.`? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polygon ambient and polygon diffuse don't have to be the same values.  For example you can have a gray object that glows green when illuminated.  Example of such thing is a modern car paint ( it has a solid color base with speckles of paint suspended in transparent overcoat.

Light source ambient and light source diffuse are also could be different colors. For example at sunset you get the ambient blue illumination from the atmosphere + very strong red/orange illumination from the sun.

Comment: "that glows green when illuminated" -- you mean, "not illuminated"?